# Crear un PDF y adjuntarlo en un email en la misma operación

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, quiero hacer una vista en la cual se crea un PDF y al mismo tiempo envia un email en el que adjunta el recien creado PDF.

Esta es la función:

```
public function envio(EnvioRequest $request){
    $usuarios=User::whereHas('experiencias',function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('sector_empresa',$request->sector);
    })->get();

    if(count($usuarios)==0)
        return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario con experiencia en este sector']);
    else{
        return PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo_sector', compact('usuarios'))->download('Curriculo.pdf');
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new Adjuntar($request->sector));
        return back()->with('message',['success','Correo enviado.']);
    }
}
```

Se utiliza un archivo Mail llamado Adjuntar.php, que tiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Adjuntar extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $sector;

    public function __construct($sector){
        $this->sector=$sector;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('correo.adjunto')->attach('C:/Users/pcx/Downloads/Curriculo.pdf');
    }
}
```

Y lleva al fichero adjunto.blade.php:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Información de los usuarios con experiencia en {{$sector}}</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <p>Saludos, nos ponemos en contacto con vuestra empresa para mostraros una lista de candidatos a trabajar para vuestra empresa.</p><br>
    <p>Todos empleados que aparecen en el PDF adjunto tiene experiencia laboral en {{$sector}}.</p><br>
    <p>Atentamente, Bolsa Empleo San Fernando.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Respecto al PDF, se trata de esta vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <?php
        $limite=count($usuarios);
    ?>

    @forelse($usuarios as $usuario)
        @include('pdf.datos_personales')
        @if($limite>1)
            <hr><hr>
            <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
            {{$limite--}}
        @endif
    @empty
    Se ha producido un error...
    @endforelse
    <h1>Para más información, ponganse en contacto con {{\App\User::administrador}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Y el archivo datos_personales.blade.php:

```
<?php
    $formaciones=$usuario->formacion;
    $idiomas=$usuario->idiomas;
    $experiencias=$usuario->experiencias;
?>

<font size="17" style="display: inline;">Datos del usuario</font> <img style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" align="right" src="{{url($usuario->ruta())}}"/>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Residencia</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Vehiculo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $usuario->name }} {{ $usuario->second_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->direccion }} ({{ $usuario->localidad }}, {{ $usuario->provincia }})</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->telefono }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->dni }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if($usuario->vehiculo)
                        Es poseedor de vehiculo propio
                    @else
                        No posee vehiculo propio
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php
        $forma=count($formaciones);
        $exp=count($experiencias);
        $idi=count($idiomas);
    ?>

    <hr>

    @if($forma>0)
        <h3>Cursos realizados</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Grado</th>
                    <th>Centro</th>
                    <th>Finalización</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($formaciones as $formacion)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$formacion->titulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{$formacion->grado}}</td>
                        <td>{{$formacion->centro}}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($formacion->finalizacion)
                                {{$formacion->anyio_finalizacion}}
                            @else
                                No
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            @empty
                Se ha producido un error
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha hecho ningun curso formativo</h3>
    @endif

    <hr>

    @if($idi>0)
        <h3>Idiomas estudiados</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Idioma</th>
                    <th>Nivel de habla</th>
                    <th>Nivel de escritura</th>
                    <th>Titulo oficial</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($idiomas as $idioma)
                <tbody>
                    <td>{{$idioma->idioma}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->nivel_hablado}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->nivel_escrito}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->titulo_oficial}}</td>
                </tbody>
            @empty
                Se ha producido un error
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha estudiado ningun idioma</h3>
    @endif

    <hr>

    @if($exp>0)
        <h3>Experiencia Laboral</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Puesto</th>
                <th>Función realizada</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>
                <th>Sector</th>
                <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                <th>Fecha de finalización</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @forelse($experiencias as $experiencia)
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->puesto}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->funcion_realizada}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->empresa}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->sector_empresa}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->mes_anyo_inicio}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->mes_anyo_fin}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        @empty
            Se ha producido un error
        @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No tiene experiencia laboral</h3>
    @endif
```

Mi problema esta en `return PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo_sector', compact('usuarios'))->download('Curriculo.pdf');`, ya que al escribir el return eso impide que tras generar el PDF se realice el resto de operaciones.
¿Como consigo que tras crear el PDF se genere el email?

Edito: He probado a crear un Job. La idea es que creo el job para que prepare el envio del email y despues creo el PDF que debera adjuntarse.

La función quedaria así:

```
public function envio(EnvioRequest $request){
    $usuarios=User::whereHas('experiencias',function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('sector_empresa',$request->sector);
    })->get();

    if(count($usuarios)==0)
        return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario con experiencia en este sector']);
    else{
        Envio::dispatch($request)->delay(now()->addSeconds(5));
        return PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo_sector', compact('usuarios'))->download('Curriculos.pdf');
    }
}
```

El job Envio.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use \App\Http\Requests\EnvioRequest;
use Mail;
use \App\Mail\Adjuntar;

class Envio implements ShouldQueue{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $destino, $sector;

    public function __construct(EnvioRequest $request){
        $destino=$request->email;
        $sector=$request->sector;
    }

    public function handle(){
        Mail::to($destino)->send(new Adjuntar($sector));
    }
}
```

Pero me veo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función handle no reconoce las variables. Similar me pasa en la función build de los ficheros Mail.

Actualizo:
Actualmente así tengo la función para crear el PDF y enviar el correo:

```
public function envio(EnvioRequest $request){
        $usuarios=User::whereHas('experiencias',function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('sector_empresa',$request->sector);
        })->get();

        if(count($usuarios)==0)
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario con experiencia en este sector']);
        else{
            Envio::dispatch($request->email,$request->sector)->delay(now()->addSeconds(5));
            return PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo_sector', compact('usuarios'))->download('Curriculos del sector '.$this->sector.'.pdf');
        }
    }
```

El fichero Envio.php:

```
class Envio implements ShouldQueue{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $email, $sector;

    public function __construct($email,$sector){
        $this->email=$email;
        $this->sector=$sector;
    }

    public function handle(){
        Mail::to($this->email)->send(new Adjuntar($this->sector));
    }
}
```

El fichero Adjuntar.php:

```
class Adjuntar extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $sector;

    public function __construct($sector){
        $this->sector=$sector;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('correo.adjunto')->attach('C:/Users/pcx/Downloads/Curriculos del sector '.$this->sector.'.pdf');
    }
}
```

Si por un lado creo el PDF y por otro ejecuto el Job, funciona, pero si lo intento todo de una vez, se cuelga el programa.
Parece ser que el programa quiere primero ejecutar el Job, ignorando mi order de retrasar la ejecución 5 segundos.

Aparte, no se si servira de algo, pero os mostrare la tabla Job que cree siguiendo el consejo que daban algunos tutoriales:

```
public function up(){
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('queue')->index();
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->unsignedTinyInteger('attempts');
            $table->unsignedInteger('reserved_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('available_at');
            $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Podría usar esta libreria [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)  y para adjuntarlo a un correo se pueden encontrar en los documentos oficiales de Laravel [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#attachments)

Comment: Y si asignas el PDF::loadview a una variable, envias el email y luego devuelves la variable del pdf??? Otra opción seria hacer un Job que ejecutarias antes del PDF::loadview en el cual enviarias el correo con el adjunto pero con un tiempo de retardo para hacer time a que este se haya creado.

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas La opción del Job suena interesante. ¿Como seria eso?

Comment: Hay un comando de artisan ke te crea el job, en realidad no es mas que una clase con un metodo que es el cuerpo de la misma que sera ejecutado cuando el job sea llamado, una vez hagas el job solo tienes que decirle con dispatch cuanto tiempo kieres ke se demore en ejecutar y correr la cola de trabajo artisan queue:work

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Así hago, aunque me he visto con un contratiempo. He actualizado mi pregunta.

Comment: Para asignarle valor y leer de $destino y $sector utiliza $this, es decir $this->destino = esto, y echo $this->destino;

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Parece que va bien. De momento descubro que parte de mis problemas derivan que no puedo usar de nombre en un pdf el caracter '/', ya que al crearse el PDF se convierte en un caracter '_' y le causa confusión al programa.

Comment: No consigo que tras el comando "Envio::dispatch", el programa se espere a que se ejecute el comando return "PDF::loadView" antes de ejecutar la sentencia. He actualizado mi pregunta.

Comment: Un consejo, no se si usaste la ruta fija C:/Users/pcx/Downloads/Curriculo.pdf sólo como ejemplo o si es parte de tu código, pero ten en cuenta que si el archivo PDF se escribe en disco en algún momento, debería crearse un archivo temporal nuevo por cada ejecución y no usar una ruta fija. Sino al generar varios PDF al mismo tiempo (varios usuarios a la vez o el mismo usuario) habría problemas de concurrencia.

Comment: Cuando ordeno que se cree el fichero este automaticamente se crea en C:/Users/pcx/Downloads, de ahi que le haya colocado esa ruta. ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar la ruta en la que se crea?

Comment: O mejor, ¿es posible que el PDF, solamente aparezca adjuntado en el email, pero que no se me cree en mi PC?

Comment: Al final lo que he hecho es hacer por un lado la creación del PDF y por otra la creación del email con el PDF.